# MAUI XAML - Can't reference property value of custom control nested inside another custom control from outside

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I would like to set the `Text` property from `MyCustomContentPage` in XAML:

File 1:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MyCustomControl" x:Class="MyCustomControl">
    <Label Text={Binding Text} />
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class MyCustomControl : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl), String.Empty);
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        Binding = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

File 2:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MyCustomGrid" x:Class="MyCustomGrid">
    <Border Content="{Binding MyCustomControl}">
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class MyCustomGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyCustomControlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyCustomControl), typeof(MyCustomControl), typeof(MyCustomGrid), null);
    public MyCustomControl MyCustomControl
    {
        get { return (MyCustomControl)GetValue(MyCustomControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCustomControlProperty, value); }
    }
    public MyCustomGrid()
    {
        Binding = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCustomControl = new MyCustomControl();
    }
}
```

File 3:

```xml
<ContentPage x:Name="MyCustomContentPage" x:Class="MyCustomContentPage">
    <MyCustomGrid MyCustomControl.Text="GOODBYE" />
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public class MyCustomContentPage : ContentPage
{
   //...
}
```

but I can't do this: `MyCustomControl.Text="GOODBYE"`, it says that:

> Bindable Text property not found on type MyCustomControl.

Thank you in advance

Comment: To improve `Binding` behavior, be sure to set `x:DataType` and make use of compiled bindings for optimizations and correctness. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. May I suggest to use a ContentView as control. In that case it would look like this. Note the Reference to ThisView

```xml
<ContentView
    x:Class="MauiTest.Controls.MessageView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="ThisView">
    <Label
        x:Name="MyLabel"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="{Binding MessageText, Source={x:Reference ThisView}}"
        TextColor="Blue"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
</ContentView>
```

To note in the code behind for the control is that you don't have a `BindingContext`. That is rarly the case when dealing with controls.

```cs
public partial class MessageView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MessageTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MessageText), typeof(string), typeof(MessageView), defaultValue: default(string));

    public string MessageText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MessageTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MessageTextProperty, value);
    }

    public MessageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In your View you have a reference to the contols

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <VerticalStackLayout
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
   
       <controls:MessageView MessageText="GOODBYE" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for response, and excuse me whether i dont explain it with my code. MyCustomGrid Is a form that contain múltiples nested CustomControls, so i want to do in XAML: <Form Client.Name="" Agent.Name="" Sale.Total="100" /> where Client, Agent, and Sale are SubControls, and i want to set their properties that way. but i dont know whether is it posible.

Comment: You can still have nested controls with this. The contentView is a container and in there you set the <Grid>. Don't use Binding or BindingContext. Rember that when you assign a Text property it is just for that property and you still need to assign that propert to the Label in your control. You can use `propertyChanged` for that. You set that in the `BindableProperty`

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I follow.

---

###### MyCustomControl

The intent of your xaml seems to have a `Label` nested in the `Grid` that "is" the custom control, which would reduce to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- 
    x:Name="MyCustomGrid" should 'not' be set here.
    That would be like a custom button saying that in every case its name should be "Button1"
 -->
<Grid
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:nested_custom_control.Controls"
    x:Class="nested_custom_control.Controls.MyCustomControl">
    <Label 
        FontSize="Medium"
        Text="{Binding Path=Text, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyCustomControl}}}"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        />
</Grid>
```

The *label* binds its own `Text` property to its parent control (as shown above) and the *control* exposes a bindable property named `Text` (as shown below).

```cs
namespace nested_custom_control.Controls;

public partial class MyCustomControl : Grid
{
    public MyCustomControl() => InitializeComponent();

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Text",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(MyCustomControl),
        defaultValue: string.Empty,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

---

Next, you explain in your comment:

> MyCustomGrid Is a form that contain múltiples nested CustomControls.

I understand that to mean that there will be a deterministic number of `MyCustomControl` in a layout determined by `MyCustomGrid` as in this minimal example.

[image: nested controls]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--     
    x:Name should not be set here. (see prev. comment)
 -->
<Grid 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:nested_custom_control.Controls"
    x:Class="nested_custom_control.Controls.MyCustomGrid"
    RowDefinitions="*,60,60,60,*"
    BackgroundColor="Azure">
    <Border         
        Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- Instance of MyCustomControl. HERE is where you name your instances. -->
        <controls:MyCustomControl 
            x:Name="myCustomControl1"
            Text="{Binding Path=UserName, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyCustomGrid}}}"/>
    </Border>
    <Border         
        Grid.Row="2">
        <controls:MyCustomControl 
            x:Name="myCustomControl2"
            Text="{Binding Path=Phone, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyCustomGrid}}}"/>
    </Border>
    <Border          
        Grid.Row="3">
        <controls:MyCustomControl 
            x:Name="myCustomControl3"
            Text="{Binding Path=Email, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyCustomGrid}}}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

To specify "what text goes where" `MyCustomGrid` is exposing bindable properties `UserName`, `Phone`, and `Email` to "direct traffic" to the intended target custom control. Again, the `MyUserControl` objects are binding their own `Text` property to different properties in the parent grid.

```cs
public partial class MyCustomGrid : Grid
{
    public MyCustomGrid() => InitializeComponent();
    public static readonly BindableProperty UserNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "UserName",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyCustomGrid),
    defaultValue: string.Empty,
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public string UserName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(UserNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PhoneProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Phone",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyCustomGrid),
    defaultValue: string.Empty,
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Phone
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PhoneProperty);
        set => SetValue(PhoneProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty EmailProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Email",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyCustomGrid),
    defaultValue: string.Empty,
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Email
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EmailProperty);
        set => SetValue(EmailProperty, value);
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

Although I realize that `MainPage` is probably going to bind this and consume it in a much more sophisticated manner, to demonstrate that values are going where they're supposed to we can put a single instance of `MyGridControl` on the main page.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:nested_custom_control.Controls"
    x:Class="nested_custom_control.MainPage">
    
    <!-- Instance of MyCustomGrid. HERE is where you name your instance. -->
    <controls:MyCustomGrid x:Name="myCustomGrid1"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Then exercise it like this.

```cs
namespace nested_custom_control
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myCustomGrid1.UserName = "Tommy IV";
            myCustomGrid1.Phone = "(000)000-0000";
            myCustomGrid1.Email = "thor@azgard.com";
        }
    }
}
```